# jQuery: How to create a new element and add it to a collection?

Tags: jquery, dom

I want to create some DOM nodes with jQuery, append them to the html while keeping them selected, so I don't need to select them again.

This is my code:

```
var foo=$('');
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var bar=$('<div>');
    $('body').append(bar);
    foo.add(bar);
}
```

Apparently foo will keep as empty in the end, so it's not gonna work. How should I deal with it without selecting all the bars in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this problem is `.add()` method does not change the original jQuery collection object, but returns a new one.

You could simply change your code to: ***[The DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/SnsPg/)***

```
var foo=$('');
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var bar=$('<div>');
    $('body').append(bar);
    foo = foo.add(bar);
}

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I was also breaking my mind with that :) But the solution was so pretty easy!

Comment: Thanks you and also @VisioN, I'll take this as accepted because it's a more native jQuery solution and you answered earlier :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array, rather than a jQuery object:

```
var foo = [];
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  var bar = $('<div>');
  $('body').append(bar);
  foo.push(bar[0]);
}
foo = $(foo);
```

Comment: I'd add `foo = $(foo);` after the `for` loop so that `foo` now points to a jQuery object containing the elements, or create a new variable that contains the jQuery object with the elements.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's not working exactly like a jQuery collection, e.g. you can't use `foo.css({'foo':'bar'})` after that.

Comment: @XunYang Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaA7z/). You'll need to modify the `foo.push(bar);` line with `foo.push(bar[0]);` so that you're storing the actual DOM element in the array, rather than the jQuery object containing the DOM element.

Comment: @rich.okelly It's a very nice answer that gets me think out of the box, after messing around with jQuery for too long :)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist A good idea, code snippet updated accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add new elements to jQuery collection use `foo = foo.add(bar)`.

Here is the updated version of your code:

```
var foo = $();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var bar = $("<div />").appendTo("body");
    foo = foo.add(bar);
}
foo.css("color", "red");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/u3efP/